# How to alias request parameter in servicestack

Tags: parameters, routes, servicestack, alias

How can I alias the DTO Customer_Code property to be the {id} parameter in my route?

```
[Route("/customers/{id}")]
Public Class Customer
{
    public string Customer_Code { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter in the route is a variable placeholder that just needs to match an existing property, the name of the property doesn't effect the routes external `/path/info` so it can be safely changed.

Use the `[DataMember]` attribute to create an alias that emits a different property name on the wire, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/customers/{Id}")]
Public Class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Customer_Code")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```